# Error (22,0) Could not find method android() for arguments

Tags: android, arguments, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Today I opened Android Studio and got a Cylic Redundancy Check Error, so I went into the cmd promp as admin and restarted my computer, it booted up and scanned my drive that was corrupted and repaired it, When it finished booting up I reopened Android Studio, and when I opened my project on Android Studio, the build failed and I got an error in my Gradle Sync, how can I go about fixing this so the project completes its build instead of failing?

**Gradle Synce Error Messages:**

```
Error:(22, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_1renfppeqp4po95v257ecguyh$_run_closure3@76bc331d] on root project 'PopularMovies' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\apple\Desktop\PopularMovies\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

**Build Gradle**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
}
dependencies {
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move that `android` closure out of the project-level `build.gradle` file and into the module's `build.gradle` file (e.g., `app/build.gradle`).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got this error because my module level `gradle` file was missing the line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

It's usually the first line in the `gradle` file.  For some unknown reason, probably being a little careless, I accidentally deleted that line, so that's how I ran into this problem.  I notice, I don't see that line in the `gradle` script above, so that's probably what's happening in this case.